# How to load whole YouTube video before playing in MPV

Tags: mpv

To load a video in the terminal with ASCII, I can do

```sh
$ mpv "<video_url>" --vo=caca
```

But some videos buffer and load frequently, and lead to many pauses.

Is there a way to load the whole video and then play it?

Comment: Use youtube-dl directly?

Comment: How? Please provide more context.

Comment: Oh come on: https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl